# Snort & Logging

Tags: tools, ids, logging, snort

I am looking for some support on using Snort in Windows 7.  My experience so far is using WireShark, so this is new territory to me.

I would like to use Snort to perform a trace, which, after it ends, will write the output to a logfile which I can then analyse.

I can perform a trace using:

```
snort.exe -i 3 -vd
```

But I cannot figure out to log this output.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt from [Snort Cookbook](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Snort_Cookbook/Logging,_Alerts,_and_Output_Plug-ins#Logging_to_a_Specific_File). You should be able to find what your looking for in there.

> ## Logging to a Specific File
>
> ### Problem
>
> You want to log your output to a specific file and location.
>
> ### Solution
>
> Use the `-L ttfilename/tt` option to log to a specific file:
>
> ```
> [testuser@localhost snort]# snort -L test1
> ```
>
> You can also specify a location by using the `-l ttdirectory/tt`
>   command-line option:
>
> ```
> [testuser@localhost snort]# snort -l /snort/log -L test2
> ```
>
> ### Discussion
>
> Logging traffic in binary mode is far less resource intensive than in
>   other modes. Binary files can then be reviewed later using Snort,
>   TCPDump, Ethereal, or other binary log-compatible programs.
>
> You can log to a specific file by specifying the `-L ttfilename/tt`
>   command-line option. This logs the network traffic to a binary file.
>   The following command logs all traffic to the file called test1 in the
>   default Snort log directory:
>
> ```
> [testuser@localhost snort]# snort -L test1
> ```
>
> This command creates a file called `test1.1084554709` in the
>   `/var/log/snort directory`. You can also specify a location by using the
>   `-l ttdirectory/tt` command-line option:
>
> ```
> [testuser@localhost snort]# snort -l /snort/log -L test2
> ```
>
> This command creates a file called `test1.1084554711` in the `/snort/log`
>   directory.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Windows version acts slightly differently, but should be translatable.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting this strange error:

'c:\Snort\bin>snort.exe snort -L test1

Running in packet dump mode


        --== Initializing Snort ==--

Initializing Output Plugins!

Snort BPF option: snort -L test1

pcap DAQ configured to passive.
The DAQ version does not support reload.
Acquiring network traffic from "\Device\NPF_{C01CA2EE-3374-4499-8281-344B9BF97BF
2}".
ERROR: Can't set DAQ BPF filter to 'snort -L test1' (¶;h)!
Fatal Error, Quitting..
Could not create the registry key.'

Do you know what's causing this?